# How do I remove/ignore words from gedit's spell checker dictionary?

Tags: 10.10, gedit

How do I remove/ignore words from gedit's spell checker dictionary?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open the dictionary where your words are saved and remove them. You can find these by opening the home folder, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for hidden files and navigate to `~/.config/enchant`

I myself have 1 `.dic` file in there and you can open it in `gedit`.

[image: images]

Comment: That simple? Wow!

Comment: These file are empty. Is there any other location of these files these days?

Answer (score 1):

Very good.  A little more detail might be in order. Some people might not be able to find "rinzwind" on their computer :-)  Use the terminal.

```
cd
```

(This changes to your home directory.)

```
cd ./.config/enchant
```

(Change to the enchant directory.)

```
$ ls
en_US.dic  en_US.exc
```

(The file you want is en_US.dic)

```
pico en_US.dic
```

Now edit the file to remove the word you added by mistake when you clicked the wrong button in the gedit spellcheck (that was my issue), etc.  Save and exit.

Comment: As of now, these files are empty. Is there any other location of these files these days?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help. It's been five years, and now I do not have a ~/.config/enchant directory or those files at all. I do not know why Ubuntu changes things like that.